Is live video transmission possible for 3-5km range, in a sounding rocket
I am thinking of having a live video transmission from sounding rocket to ground station,low quality video works. I do have a high gain antenna.
The expected range is around 4-5km.
frequency should be 2.4Ghz or 900Mhz.
I am new to this thing. from what i have seen on internet

The modules which drones use for transmitting data.(not sure range works for 5km), or its too expensive.
I saw some modules like TS835 and stuff but there were 5.8ghz which is not allowed, i think if i do some search i should be able to find 900mhz or 2.4ghz. but the issue is will it be enough to get the work done.
So i just want to get more info or there are any other methods through which I can proceed. like any RF stuff or something. or encoding the video and then using RF.

Any help or guidance would be truly helpful.
Thanks in advance!!

television can be transmitted via radio wave, it's digital now but wasn't always.
